# python how to finding process location/path

Tags: python-3.x, automation

i want to make a scrip to aoutomate some programs,one of the feature is opening and closing them.
for now im using the full path from the folder to open apps:

```
C:\\Users\\xxxx\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\googlechrome.exe
```

and i dont like this way, cuse its working only on my PC
do i have any way so the program can find it with out the full path?
looking in processes or somthing?
i want it to be dynamic,that if i run the same scrip on diffrent PCs he could find the path by its own.

Comment: are those executables already running?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pathfinder maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

One library may help you is this `psutil` in PyPi.

## Examples:

```py
In [7]: p = psutil.Process(17032)

In [8]: p
Out[8]: psutil.Process(pid=17032, name='pythonw.exe', status='running', started='18:29:30')

In [9]: p.exe()
Out[9]: 'C:\\Users\\[user_name]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\pythonw.exe'
```